# Fastest Schema Approach for this Table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, database-schema

I've got the following table in a SQL Server 2008 database:

- `ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL`
- `Scope CHAR(5) NOT NULL`
- `Data NVARCHAR(MAX)`

The table is rarely modified, but frequently accessed using a

```
SELECT Data 
WHERE ID = @X 
AND Scope = @Y
```

command.

`Data` can be anything from empty to several pages of text. `ID+Scope` will always be unique. The table will contain a few thousand unique IDs and less than 20 unique `Scope` values.

I'm trying make sure I'm using the best strategy for keys/indexes. At the moment I've just got primary nonclustered key set using `ID` and `Scope` (In that order).

Comment: why use uniqueidentifier, int or bigint have enormous headroom. Only a handful of DBs around the world will ever have tables that surpass their limits. That alone would reduce things and therefore speed them up.

Comment: And INT is more than enough in this case. Uniqueidentifier is for 'random access' to the next id. The ID is initally created from multiple locations, not all of which are in the DB.

Comment: Good article for not using GUIDs here... http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/guid-performance/

Comment: +1 helpful, but still don't think this will be an issue in my case as the table is rarely modified, and even the unique id itself is selected in scope (e.g. @X OP is a variable, not a parameter) so there's not the transit overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that ID alone is *not* unique, and that you are not inclined to change the ID type to INT, then what you have done is nearly optimal.

- You're using nvarchar(max) instead of ntext - this will perform better, and ntext is scheduled for deprecation
- Your Primary key is sorted first on the most-selective column (ID)

The one thing I would add is clustering your Primary Key, for better performance. This is preferable to N West's solution of *adding* a clustered index because then you would have two duplicate indexes (the PK and the clustered index) which impairs write performance with no performance gain on reads. Better to simply cluster the index you already have: the primary key.

Edited to add: Since your table is rarely updated, the use of a GUID key field should not set you back nearly as much as it would on a frequently-updated table. Not ideal, but in your *specific* situation it should have minimal impact.

Still, you may find it annoying after the first few times you have to manually type a GUID someone scrawled on a Post-It into the query window.

Comment: @Paul Make sure to put Scope as first field in the primary key. (with only a few thousand records this approach is fine.)

Comment: @FilipDeVos - Scope first, why?

Comment: @Paul Normally you put the most selective field first in a covering index, but since you only filter on the scope field it is more interesting to put that field first.

Comment: I'm filtering on both in every select...?

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ON <TableName> (ID, Scope)
```

Using a clustered index will speed up your queries since you'll just be traversing the tree to get each ID/scope.

Note that using a GUID will be slow. But it will be faster than a Heap or nonclustered scan...